# SugarCRM Project and SQL Server Constraint Issue/Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, constraints, sugarcrm

I'm stuck on an issue I hope someone has some experience with. It involves an Open Source (FREE) project I've worked on for the past three years. It's an installable package for SugarCRM CE/PRO/ENT.

JJWDesign Google Maps for SugarCRM

http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/jjwgooglemaps/

Several people have reported constraint errors with MS SQL during the install process. Servers running SugarCRM with MySQL don't have this problem. The reports are that an error occurs during installation of the Maps Package. Unfortunately, I can not test MS SQL and I can not change the database layer or installation processing by SugarCRM.

Error:

> 05/17/12 12:28:50 [6508][1][FATAL] Error altering column(s)
>   jjwg_maps_lat on table: jjwg_markers: Query Failed: ALTER TABLE
>   jjwg_markers DROP CONSTRAINT DF__jjwg_mark__jjwg___7B7B4DDC ALTER
>   TABLE jjwg_markers ALTER COLUMN jjwg_maps_lat float(10) NULL ALTER
>   TABLE jjwg_markers ADD   DEFAULT '0.00000000' FOR jjwg_maps_lat :::
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL
>   Server]'DF__jjwg_mark__jjwg___7B7B4DDC' is not a constraint.
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Could not drop
>   constraint. See previous errors.

Another error reported recently.

> SQL Error : [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL
>   Server]'DF__jjwg_mark__jjwg___1EC48A19' is not a constraint..
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Could not drop
>   constraint. See previous errors..

SugarCRM Forum Thread: The SugarCRM Forum has not be able to help with this issue, which is why I'm posting here on stackoverflow.com.

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/jjwdesign-google-maps-addon-installation-issue-80206/

It seems like the Float field type is the cause of the issue. SugarCRM thinks that it needs to remove a constraint from this field, but when it tried to do so, the constraint does not exist. Perhaps there is a way to setup MS SQL to ignore these types of errors?

Thanks, Jeff Walters

Answer (score 2):

I see this on other MSSQL installs all the time. SugarCRM just doesn't handle MSSQL well when it comes to the Quick Repair/Rebuild (or install process as you are seeing). It always generates this SQL. I just tell my clients to ignore it. Obviously that is not the best answer for a distributable solution like yours.

Comment: Thanks for answering Eggs. Do you know if there is a way of setting MSSQL to ignore the error? Users are not sure if the install has fully completed.

Comment: I don't, but if there isn't a way to ignore the errors then perhaps you could use some jQuery to hide those errors.